# Visual Studio disassembly - `else` keyword on wrong line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, disassembly

Here is a piece of code I have in a function:

```
while (true)
{
  if (some_condition_here)
  {
    // ...
  }
  else
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When debugging and looking at VS's disassembly window, I see the following assembly along with corresponding source lines shown:

```
while (true)
DF3E9E4C  xor         eax,eax  
DF3E9E4E  cmp         eax,1  
DF3E9E51  je          DF3E9EBAh
{
  if (some_condition_here)
DF3E9E53  ; condition     
DF3E9E6E  test        eax,eax  
DF3E9E70  je          DF3E9EA3h  
  {
DF3E9E72  ; ...
DF3E9E9B  ; last line, no jump
  }
  else
; jump to end of if-else block
DF3E9EA1  jmp         DF3E9EB8h
  {
DF3E9EA3  ; ...
  }
}
; jump to start of while loop
DF3E9EB8  jmp         DF3E9E4Ch
```

If we examine the end of the `if` block and the beginning of the `else` block:

```
DF3E9E9B  ; last line, no jump
  }
  else
; jump to end of if-else block
DF3E9EA1  jmp         DF3E9EB8h
  {
```

We can clearly see that the `else` keyword appears one line earlier than where it should be:

```
DF3E9E9B  ; last line, no jump
  }
; jump to end of if-else block
DF3E9EA1  jmp         DF3E9EB8h
  else
  {
```

Is this a bug in VS, or is there a specific reason for such a mismatch? Perhaps I am missing something crucial?

Comment: This is entirely normal.  A consequence of how the code generator works from the parser state.  If there was no `else` block then there would be no `jmp` instruction either.  The jmp won't be emitted *until* the parser has detected the else.  So you see the else first.  It is otherwise entirely inconsequential.

Comment: @Hans I kinda suspected that, but I figured that VS might account for such things and interleave the source lines appropriately... Regardless, you can post that as an answer and I would happily accept it!